# How to sort a file in bash based on the one column of the file

Tags: bash, sorting

I have text file, composed of 5 columns and I want to sort each line based on the fourth column of the file, any idea?

I put some lines of the file below to make it more clear.

```
0 27000000 spk1 -5865.438965
0 27000000 spk10 -6069.150879
0 27000000 spk6 -6070.252930
0 27000000 spk17 -6211.137695
0 27000000 spk12 -6256.836426
0 27000000 spk7 -6259.441895
0 27000000 spk16 -6307.564453
```

Comment: You mentioned 5 columns but your example input shows only 4?

Comment: Have you read the man page for `sort` yet?

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
$ sort -n -t ' ' -k 4 test.txt
0 27000000 spk16 -6307.564453
0 27000000 spk7 -6259.441895
0 27000000 spk12 -6256.836426
0 27000000 spk17 -6211.137695
0 27000000 spk6 -6070.252930
0 27000000 spk10 -6069.150879
0 27000000 spk1 -5865.438965
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use sort command and define the field to sort base on it and the field separator like the following

```
sort -t" " -k4 filename
```